Wiring a new 3-way switch with 2 white and 2 black wires
Replacing an old Leviton 3-way switch. The old switch was wired as follows: https://imgur.com/a/36NQmAe. The black on the top-left is hot. I'm not sure how to wire the remaining 3 wires. This is the new switch I'm installing: https://www.homedepot.com/p/Leviton-Decora-15-Amp-3-Way-Switch-White-R62-05603-2WS/100078412

Quite sure the old switch is a four way.  Three ways only have three screws.  Four ways are usually used with two three ways in the circuit, usually in the centre.

Oh! Do I need a different new switch then? Perhaps https://www.homedepot.com/pep/Leviton-Decora-15-Amp-4-Way-Switch-White-R58-05604-2WS/100357021?

I imagine so.  Three way switches can be confusing enough.  Adding a four way is way above what I am comfortable with unless new construction and with pictures.
